# Start application from a numbered list of choices

Tags: windows, command-line, shell

I want to display all applications dynamically within a folder in a numbered list, and launch them by entering the number associated with the application.

So far I have the easy part working, the numbered display - but I'm stumped as how to associate the number input with a way to launch the specific application.

```
@echo off

echo NirSoft Tools
echo.

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set num=0

for %%e in (*.exe) do (
    set /a num += 1
    echo !num! %%~ne
)

echo.
set /p choice="Enter Choice: "

endlocal

echo.
pause
```

And the output looks like this:

```
NirSoft Tools

1 BulkFileChanger
2 FileTypesMan
3 IconsExtract
4 nircmd
5 nircmdc
6 ShellBagsView
7 ShellExView
8 ShellMenuNew
9 ShellMenuView

Enter Choice:
```

The crucial part is missing, the way to start the selected app by its number. Is that even possible with the Windows commandline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I came up with minimal additions (3 lines), and keeps it dynamic (for when directory contents/number of options changes):

```
@echo off

echo NirSoft Tools
echo.

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set num=0

for %%e in (*.exe) do (
    set /a num += 1
    set opt!num!=%%~ne
    echo !num! %%~ne
)

echo.
set /p choice="Enter Choice: "

set newchoice=opt%choice%
start !%newchoice%!

endlocal

echo.
pause
```

What's going on here with these additions?

The `set opt!num!=%%~ne` line creates a new variable for each option (`opt1`, `opt2`, etc.) and each of those contains the file name that's associated with it.

The `set newchoice=opt%choice%` line creates a new variable named "newchoice" that references the `opt#` variable, where the `#` is the number you picked as your choice in the previous line.  So if you pick `5`, the `newchoice` variable will contain `opt5`.

The `start !%newchoice%!` line will run whatever filename is in that `opt#` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works beautifully. I will have to read up on the combinations of delayed expansion (!...!) and regular (%...%) variables - this seems quite powerful.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways. Either continue with what you have now and add the following:

```
if %choice%==1 goto BulkFileChanger
if %choice%==2 goto FiletypesMan
...
if %choice%==9 goto ShellMenuView

goto end

:BulkFileChanger
REM command here

:FiletypesMan
REM command here

etc...

:end
```

Alternatively and better, replace the `set /p` with the following:

```
choice /c 123456789 /m Enter Choice:
if errorlevel 2 goto FiletypesMan
if errorlevel 1 goto BulkFileChanger

etc...
```

The advantage of choice over set is that you press the key and then it proceeds. No enter necessary. Also, it won't continue on false input. Note that you have to list the errorlevel choices from 9 to 1.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep the whole selection process dynamic, for when programs are added or deleted from that folder. I should have mentioned that more specifically in my question.

Comment: Both options work, although the choice one requires a bit more configuration if that changes. The first one still works perfectly. It just adds to your script, executing the launch of programs. But I seem to have forgotten the `goto end` after a program has launched. But I did miss the part about dynamically create the menu.